# Replacing old shower flange

Tags: plumbing, flange

We are remodeling our master bath. We have a terrazzo floor with a concrete “channel” they installed the plumbing with. We removed the top portion of the old shower drain but are stuck on what to do next. We intended on putting in a Schluter flange with a Schluter shower pan that requires no mortar bed. We know the new flange needs to be in the ground and attached to PVC drain pipe. How do we get this old piece out? Do we give up on the Schluter flange and go with something different? Any advice for us DIYers who are learning as we go would be appreciated. I’ve seen other threads here with similar issues but not quite the same. [image]

Answer (score 0):

If you are dead set on using the Schluter pan, you have to use the schluter drain.  that means you have to cut out the existing drain.

you will need an [internal PVC cutter](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Husky-Internal-Diameter-PVC-Pipe-Cutter-80-525-111/304341675?source=shoppingads&locale=en-US&pla&mtc=SHOPPING-BF-ARM-GGL-Multi-Multi-NA-NA-NA-PLALIA-NA-RBA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-ALL_IN_TEST_SIMPSEEK&cm_mmc=SHOPPING-BF-ARM-GGL-Multi-Multi-NA-NA-NA-PLALIA-NA-RBA-NA-NA-NBR-NA-NA-NA-ALL_IN_TEST_SIMPSEEK-71700000109986253-58700008375337184-92700076237673671&gclid=Cj0KCQjwvL-oBhCxARIsAHkOiu1QnowlQ6f8EgunALLC2zjaiK72kyC1sSLLS9nxG4gQM-Y5lGIkp4AaAk2bEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds). How deep you need to cut, and will you need to chip out concrete around your cut to add the schluter drain is unknown until the top of the old shower drain is cut out.

For that reason when I am rehabbing an old shower with a good drain, I go to the [Shower slope kits](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Goof-Proof-Shower-Pre-Pitch-Standard-Installation-Kit-PPK-201/202822315).  Yes you have to add a mortar bed, but it eliminates all the cutting and chipping and glueing needed for the Schluter system.  The rods are a guide to slope the mortar.

I use a waterproofing over the dried mortar, so any water weeping between tiles will be guided to the drain. ( additionally I use cement backer board on all the walls and coat them with [Waterproofing](https://www.flooranddecor.com/mapei-installation-materials/mapei-mapelastic-aqua-defense-100056415.html?utm_content=M-Shopping&utm_term=&gclid=Cj0KCQjwvL-oBhCxARIsAHkOiu1bQvwBtzbLefNf3g1C3DPRcJqTjNJ_b2mH4d-UDasL6x54aOaex-QaAsJHEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) along with the floor.)

You then have a complete waterproof shower.

Answer (score 0):

Schluter makes an adapter kit for use with your existing "clamping" drain assembly. You use this kit instead of the regular Schluter drain to adapt for use with the Schluter pre-fab pan. You don't have to remove the existing lower drain piece or mess with the pipe below. See here: [Schluter Kerdi Drain A Adapter Kit](https://www.schluter.com/schluter-us/en_US/Shower-System/Drains/Adaptor-Drains/Schluter%C2%AE-KERDI-DRAIN-A/p/KERDI_DRAIN-AR?facets=false)